# What is this external telephone wire cover called?

Tags: electrical, wiring

What is the correct term for this external telephone wire cover? I have searched for external telephone cover and similar terms but can't see one to order.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was once a brand name (and still is) but you'll often hear covers of this sort called Wiremold, which also describes the rectangular wiring cover below the box. In my years of cable television, I've probably seen dozens of different designs of telephone covers. I would expect that you may not find an exact match, unless you happen across new-old-stock somewhere.

My quick Google search shows that even Google considers Wiremold to be a generic term for plastic wire routing covers, typically surface mounted.

Most of the US telephone companies combine the cover with the demark with terminology to indicate that it's the "consumer interface module" or similar wording.

Because it's low voltage wiring, it's also unlikely that your zoning codes have specific requirements. You should be able to find something to your liking in a big box store or online, searching wiremold telephone cover.

I found this on Amazon:
[https://www.amazon.com/OUTDOOR-CABLETEK-ENCLOSURE-UTILITY-CABLE/dp/B00BMVV758/ref=pd_sim_60_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=Z9AMC9Q9J088Q2ZD1K1J](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BMVV758)

[image]

Comment: That is not a WireMold product. Looks to me like a proprietary phone company part. ............... Also, the image you link is an outdoor splice box or network interface box, not a wire/cable cover or wireway.

Comment: yep, that's a fair description. From the posting, one is led to believe that the objective is to replace the cover. As a proprietary telephone company box, it would be near impossible to find a direct replacement. My post was to assist Ecnerwal to find something suitable for his purposes. Anything that covers the hole and contains the wiring would be akin to Wiremold or similar company product line.